# How to turn off spring security auto-configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have an application.yml like this:

```yaml
spring:
    security:
      oauth2:
        resourceserver:
          jwt:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev
            
spring-security:
  provider: 
    default
```

```
spring-security:
  provider: 
    keycloak
```

So I use a keycloak in the background but I have a `spring-security.provider` properties what can be `default` and `keycloak`.

If I use the `default` I do not want spring security to work so I don't even start the keycloak. But if the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` is set, it tries to build up a connection to my keycloak while it should not.

I would like the application to ignore the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` if the `spring-security.provider` is set to `default'.

At the moment I have two configuration classes based on `spring-security.provider`:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring-security", value = "provider", havingValue = "default", matchIfMissing = true)
public class DefaultSecurityConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf()
            .disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring-security", value = "provider", havingValue = "keycloak", matchIfMissing = false)
@Configuration
public class KeycloakSecurityConfigurer {

    private final SpringSecurity springSecurity;
    private final RolesConverter authoritiesExtractor;

    // @formatter:off
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {      
        http
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(springSecurity.getApiMatcher())
        .authenticated()
        .pathMatchers("/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor());

        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> grantedAuthoritiesExtractor() {
        return new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(authoritiesExtractor);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable spring security auto-configuration by using
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })`
annotation above your main class (which contain main method)
Or
by adding this configuration into the application.properties file:
`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration`
There are also some particular cases in which this setup isn't quite enough.
For example, almost each Spring Boot application is started with Actuator in the classpath. This causes problems because another auto-configuration class needs the one we've just excluded, so the application will fail to start.
In order to fix this issue, we need to exclude that class; and, specific to the Actuator situation, we need to exclude ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.

Comment: This, plus an `@Import(SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)` on top of `KeycloakSecurityConfigurer` to add it back

Answer (score 0):

Create config, for example in `src/main/resources`: `application-no-security.yml:`

```yaml
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: >
      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Activate it, for example:

```java
@ActiveProfile("no-security")
class SomeTest {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If solutions from previous answers do not work you can also try disabling OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

This worked for me